# _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "pyimage2"

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to draw an image onto a canvas (mid conversion from place to canvas) and this error appears

hastebin containing code:
http://hastebin.com/tuciyisisa.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Stuff\python\Coursework\AQADo\main.py", line 82, in <module>
    app = Application(master=root)
  File "D:\Stuff\python\Coursework\AQADo\main.py", line 74, in __init__
    self.drawCounter(space_y, current_space, game_canvas)
  File "D:\Stuff\python\Coursework\AQADo\main.py", line 26, in drawCounter
    canvas.create_image(170, space_y[current_space["1a"]], counter1)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2291, in create_image
    return self._create('image', args, kw)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2282, in _create
    *(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "pyimage2"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
canvas.create_image(170, space_y[current_space["1a"]], counter1)
```

There seems to be a problem with your function signature here. [`create_image`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.create_image-method) expects a `position` tuple, plus keyword arguments. Try:

```
canvas.create_image((170, space_y[current_space["1a"]]), image=counter1)
```

Now your application runs without any apparent errors.

[image]

Comment: Replaced it with the line `canvas.create_image((90, space_y[current_space["1a"]]), image=counter1)
` and it does not draw yet having no error 

Seems to be an issue with the background image however

Comment: Strange, works on my machine. What version of Python are you using? What operating system are you using? Are you using an IDE? Are you running the script from the command line? Are you pasting it into the [repl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop)?

Comment: See my edit, it's my fault. Thanks.

Edit again:
Seems like it's not drawing it onto the screen I use `canvas.create_image((90, space_y[current_space["1a"]]), image=counter1, anchor=NW)`